# Convert Symfony 2 FormType with choice_list closure to Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I migrated some Sf2 form types to Sf3 without any problem... but this one is causing me some trouble.

```
class StaticEntityType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param OptionsResolver $resolver
     */
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'function' => 'getAll',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'group_by' => null,
                'choice_list' => function (Options $options) {
                    return new ObjectChoiceList(
                        call_user_func(array($options['class'], $options['function'])),
                        $options['choice_label'],
                        $options['preferred_choices'],
                        $options['group_by'],
                        'id'
                    );
                }
            ]
        );
        $resolver->setRequired('class');
        $resolver->setDefined(['function', 'choice_label', 'group_by']);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'static_entity';
    }
}
```

The option list should be created relative to options "class" and "function", like this:

```
$formBuilder->add('myField', StaticEntityType::class, ['class' => '\Path\To\MyStaticEntity', 'function' => 'getAll'])
```

But since `choice_list` option and `ObjectChoiceList` no longer exists, I don't find how to do.

Doc says that we should either provide 'choices' or 'choice_loader'. But 'choices' don't accept closure, and 'choice_loader' don't receive the form options list.

Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally found a solution!

In fact, the `OptionResolver` class allows to set a Normalizer, which will be called at runtime when getting an option.

So I removed the `choice_list` option, and instead of adding the `choices` option, I added a Normalizer:

```
    $resolver->setNormalizer(
        'choices',
        function (Options $options) {
            return call_user_func([$options['class'], $options['function']]);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

As described in the [migration guide](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-3.0.md):

> The
>   `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\ChoiceList\ObjectChoiceList`
>   class has been removed in favor of
>   `Symfony\Component\Form\ChoiceList\ArrayChoiceList`.

And

> The `choice_list` option of `ChoiceType` was removed.

Simply use `choice`.

So try as follow:

```
$resolver->setDefaults(
            [
                'function' => 'getAll',
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'group_by' => null,
                'choice' => function (Options $options) {
                    return new ArrayChoiceList(
                        call_user_func(array($options['class'], $options['function'])),
                        $options['choice_label'],
                        $options['preferred_choices'],
                        $options['group_by'],
                        'id'
                    );
                }
            ]
        );
```

Other [resources](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html) here in the doc.

Hope this help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But the `choice` option does not exists. Maybe you talked about `choices` option, but like I said, it doesn't accept closure. (Additionally, the ArrayChoiceList constructor only takes 2 arguments)